# Using beef jerky cuts for stir fry?

Tags: substitutions, beef, stir-fry, jerky

I have some cuts of beef intended to be used for beef jerky.
I have not yet dried them -- the meat is still fresh.
I don't know what cut of meat was used.  Can I use it for stir fry?

Comment: Jerky as in "dried" or as in "fresh, had planned to dry it"? Welcome to the site!

Comment: The jerky is fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Just my own opinion but I think if the cuts are made across the grain rather than with the grain it should be fine. With the grain might be tough to chew. There are 2 camps on cutting jerky meats so it really depends on how it was cut.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Since it doesn't have fat on it, I thought it best to cut cross grain and stir fry for a short time.

Comment: Did the stir-fry really make a difference in the meat's flavor? I think beef jerky is an already pretty cooked and very dry food. I would guess it would add a lot to any dish, but will gain very little from recooking.  So how did it turn out?

Comment: The meat was cut for beef jerky, not made into beef jerky.

Answer (score 0):

If it's cut thin enough, and if a visual inspection shows little in the way of sinew and connective tissue, I'd say you should be fine.

Interestingly, I have been doing the opposite recently. I have a lot of beef cut for stir fry / schnitzel, etc... that I've instead used for Beef Jerky. It's been working well.

Comment: Well speaking of that, you could pound out the jerky cuts to soften them up too

Answer (score 0):

Look for authentic recipes for machaca con huevos, Chihuahua-style. Not quite stir fry, pounded or shredded jerky cooked in a skillet with eggs and tomatoes, but it's getting there. It is common at Mexican restaurants on the US West Coast but usually made with fresh roasted or braised brisket, although I occasionally see the jerky version and a few other jerky dishes on menus. I also see the jerky in Mexican markets but I can't remember what they call it or any of the other dishes except machaca.

Good luck!